# hosting symfony in a virtual directory on nginx

Tags: symfony, nginx

I'm trying to host a symfony app in a virtual folder and using url rewriting with nginx.

Following various examples I found, I'm stuck with something like that:

```
    upstream phpfcgi {
        server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        server_name localhost;

        root /realpath/Symfony/web/;

        [ssl stuff]

        # strip app.php/ prefix if it is present
        rewrite ^/app_dev\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

        location /virtual{
            alias /realpath/Symfony/web/;
            index app_dev.php;
            try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
        }

        location @rewriteapp {
            rewrite ^/virtual/(.*)$ /app_dev.php/$1 last;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server from upstream phpfcgi
        location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_pass phpfcgi;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        }
    }
```

If I remove the  `/virtual` from the two first locations , it's working fine.
Should I set the SCRIPT_URI on the third location?

Thanks for your help

Comment: are you sure `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;`  is correct? errors, we need more error messages

Comment: without the /virtual, it seems it's the case as the app runs fine. With the virtual, the app_dev.php file is found but symfony doesn't found the route. `No route found for "GET /virtual" `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, see the added line:

```
location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass phpfcgi;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    # Add this line:
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /virtual$fastcgi_script_name;

    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
}
```